# browser auto fill event

Tags: javascript, browser, cross-browser

I am doing some website where I have a login form. I know people can save their usernames and passwords on these in their web browsers.

I need to show / hide a label (`<label></label>`). if the field is empty then the label has to appear, if there is any value in the field then the label has to hide,
but this doesn't work with the browser autocomplete, is there anyway I can track this?

I tried with:

```
jQuery.change();
```

but that doesn't work.

Is there anything I can do about this rather than turning autocomplete off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The norm here is to use the **placeholder** attribute on the relevant *input* element:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="username">
```

`username` will be displayed within the input when there's no text, and hidden otherwise. If you're using this, then you should probably also use something like [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) to detect support and create a normal text label otherwise.

Comment: It works on *most modern browsers* and as you can see, even SO uses it for its search field (top right corner of the page)

Answer (score 0):

You have to manually trigger the change event:

```
$("#username")
.change(function () {
    // do stuff on change (check for default)
})
.trigger("change");
```

or use some watermark library if you only want to toggle default text (or the placeholder attribute with Modernizr as **aviraldg** recommends).

Answer (score -1):

This is very simple.
I use this for my site's text fields.

This coding is in Javascript text.

1. create a `<form>` with name and `id = "comform"` (you can change this later; just for reference).
2. create an `<input type = "text"` with `name` and `id = "Message"` (you can change this later; just for reference).
3. create a `<div>` with `id = "ifsend"` (you can change this later; just for reference).

Also create a variable to store the length in. var numbering (you can change this later; just for reference).

```
function counter() {
    var numbering;
    numbering = document.forms["comform"]["Message"].value.length;
    if (numbering == 0) {
        label();
    }
    if (numbering != 0) {
        document.getElementById('ifsend').innerHTML="";
    }
}

function label() {
    document.getElementById('ifsend').innerHTML="Your form value is empty";
}
```

Comment: And how is this not helpful? You didn't ask for a specific language and you want to count the number of items in a field, correct?